# CreateJS, Implement Speech Bubbles

Tags: javascript, java, html, createjs

I'm working on a pretty basic visual novel creator with createjs and a bunch of other libraries that lets me render video. For now I'm stuck on this part that I really don't know how to work it out.

I want to implement Speech Bubbles, the ones that I already have are really Ugly, but they're made with the vector graphics API of createjs so I can scale them as much as I want without losing quality. I want to make a more stylish speech bubbles, with colorful borders that makes them more apealing to the eyes, (or at least can match the graphic style used in the assets), I don't think that using an entire sprite will work because, well I can't scale them up withou losing quality, and many others things that are bad will happen.

What you guys advice me to do?. I'm really struggling in this part :$

P.S.
Here's the site if you guys want to check it out. Is in spanish but I think you guys can work out the way to use the editor. ONLY WORKS ON CHROME!

http://www.skiboo.com.mx/video_editor_test/

P.P.S.
English is not my native languague so please bear with me.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the ScaleBitmap "extra" in the EaselJS GitHub. This allows you to use a single image, sliced up into a 3x3 grid, with the corners unscaled, the sides stretched on one-axis, and the center stretched to fill the space. Interestingly enough, the example that it uses is a speech bubble :)

- Source: https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/tree/master/extras/ScaleBitmap
- Example: https://rawgit.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/master/extras/ScaleBitmap/ScaleBitmap.html

Note that you can do a lot with vector graphics if you use something like Illustrator or Flash Pro (now Adobe Animate) to create them. Flash can export CreateJS graphics, and there are tools like http://drawscri.pt that can export Illustrator content.

Comment: Wow thanks for the tools. I'm totally checking it out. Kinda solved that problem for now, I'm gonna implement some Dialog Boxes like the ones seen in old RPG games.

Something like this

http://bit.ly/1Raf8qP

Thanks for that info, I'm totally playing with it! :D